# howto increase the displayed stringvalue of a variable in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

i am in debug mode and like to watch a string variable. the content of the string is quite big and when watching it, it shows only a part of it and ends with '...'.

I went through all settings and did not found a way to increase the displayed value.

is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "variables" view, right-click in the lower section of the display (the "details pane") and hit "Max length...".  In the resulting dialog, you can enter a max # of characters, or 0 for unlimited.  Tested in Eclipse 4.4.0, I'm not sure about other versions.

Comment: Perfect. Thats the solution. Thanks a lot.